# Why are LogPlot results different to Plot of log results?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following function for which I want to generate a LogPlot for:

```
JB[dB_, M_, a_] := (10^(dB/10) M (M - 1) (2 M - 1))/3 + ((a - 1) (2 a - 1))/(Pi^2 (a - 2))
```

A simple `LogPlot[1/JB[x, 16, 1], {x, -40, 15}]` generates the following desired output:

[image: LogPlot]

However, if I try to first generate the data and then make a plot, I get different results. Namely:

```
Boundresults = Table[{x, Log[1/JB[x, 16, 1]] // N}, {x, -40, 15, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Boundresults]
```

which generates:

[image: ListPlot]

Why are the two results different?

Comment: @user6014, version 11.3

Comment: If you use `Log10` instead of `Log` you get an equivalent plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a log plot, you need to scale both the data and the vertical axis. Your [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) only scales the data. Why not use [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot):

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{x,1/JB[x,16,1]//N},{x,-40,15,0.01}]]
```

[image]

or [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) with scaling functions:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x,1/JB[x,16,1]//N},{x,-40,15,0.01}], ScalingFunctions->{None, "Log"}]
```

[image]